# Testing multiple useEffects with Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the below component utilizing Jest and Enzyme. The `useEffect` hooks are not getting called at all if I use `render` and `act` from `testing-library/react`.

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MultiUseEffects() {
  const [checkState, setCheckState] = useState(false);
  const [anotherCheckState, setAnotherCheckState] = useState(true);
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckState(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnotherCheckState(false);
  }, [checkState]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setInputVal("Value is Changed");
  };

  return (
    <div id="MultiUseEffects">
      MultiUseEffects {anotherCheckState ? "State TRUE" : "State FALSE"}
      <Button variant="contained" id="valueChangeBtn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Change State
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MultiUseEffects;
```

Comment: Which test library are you having problems with, enzyme or RTL?